# How to upgrade to glx 1.3 on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: firefox, opengl

Recently I installed Firefox 10.00 after which it crashes when I start it. It reported that

```
GLXtest process failed (exited with status 1): GLX version older than the required 1.3
```

My glx info

```
glxinfo | grep version
server glx version string: 1.2
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.2
OpenGL version string: 1.4 Mesa 7.7.1
```

How to update it?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to read [this discussion](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=659932).

I fixed this problem by installing newer Xorg packages using the `xorg-edgers` PPA. Add it with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Note that you do not need to enter any further commands to install specific packages; adding the `xorg-edgers` PPA and running regular updates is the correct usage.

If you need to remove the PPA, you must use `ppa-purge`, or you may run into serious issues. Please read the [instructions on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa).

Comment: With `sudo apt-get update` you are not actually installing anything. After that you might want to run `sudo apt-get upgrade` to actually update the packages that the PPA has different versions for.